# fatal error : 'couldn't connect to host' ! (Facebook API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add Facebook API on my web application..

But when I tried to post links using the Graph API.. I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with
>   message 'couldn't connect to host' in
>   /home/u614270703/public_html/test/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:156
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/u614270703/public_html/test/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(248):
>   Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send('https://graph.f...',
>   'POST', Array) #1 /home/u614270703/public_html/test/session2.php(32):
>   Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/u614270703/public_html/test/vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
>   on line 156

I don't have any idea what is going on. What does this error means? I don't know why I can't 'connect to host'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server probably blocks outgoing CURL requests, contact your provider and ask him if he could open access to the Facebook API server (graph.facebook.com).

There are other threads about this too:

- [Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in ....src/base_facebook.php on line 887](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865077/fatal-error-uncaught-curlexception-7-couldnt-connect-to-host-thrown-in-s)
- [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425406/facebook-api-exception-object-error-on-facebook-app